# nautilus: open-with but don't change default

Tags: fedora, gnome3, nautilus

In recent versions of Gnome (Gnome 3.30 on Fedora 29, if it matters), it seems that when using right-click "Open With Other Application" from Nautilus, the option in the Select Application dialog to set the selected application as default has been removed, such that it now simply ALWAYS sets the application as default. I like to use open-with-other as a one-off thing, leaving the default as it was, so this behavior is disruptive to me.

Is there a way to change this behavior so that it does not conflate open-with-other and changing the default application? I assume there's at least a dconf/gsettings value I can change, but I can't find it.

Note that I am NOT asking how to set default applications - I am asking how to use open-with-other but without ALSO changing the default automatically.

EDIT: Added fedora tag

Comment: Nautilus 3.30.3 here as well, but Fedora. Maybe this is Fedora-specific?

Answer (score 10):

[This is a known bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/issues/1026)

What you can do is:

1. right-click-open your file with a secondary application
2. right-click on the file and go to properties -> Open With
3. Set your default application here

It should be persistent now

Alternatively you can set the entry in `~/.config/mimeapps.list` in the `[Default Applications]` section.

Comment: You're right, I misread the bug description, it's unrelated. My solution should still work.

Comment: I found the correct ticket. As to why you can't reproduce it. It may be because the bug got fixed in a more recent version of Fedora. It still exists in Arch, as Arch does not patch upstream bugs.

Comment: That last comment explains everything (I'm using Arch). Guess I'll have to wait for a new version, or compile myself.